# How to add hover effect in React Native for mobile and web app?

Tags: css, typescript, react-native, web, nativewind

I am developing an application using React Native and I would like to create a consistent user experience for both mobile devices and the web. However, I'm facing difficulties in replicating the :hover effect in React Native for the web version of my app.

I understand that :hover is a specific pseudo-selector for interactions in browsers, and React Native doesn't directly support it. However, I would like to know if there is any way to create a similar hover effect in React Native.

I did some research and found some solutions suggesting using touch events (onPress, onPressIn, onPressOut, etc.) in combination with the nativewind library to create a hover-like experience. but that's not what i want

I would like to know if anyone has faced this challenge before or if there is any recommended approach to adding the hover effect in React Native, but only for the web version. How can I create different styles and behaviors when the user hovers over a specific component in the web app?

I appreciate any help or guidance you can provide!

Comment: add onMouseEnter={() => setShow(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setShow(false)} function